# Converting excel to csv with Microsoft Interop and ignoring thousands separator

Tags: c#, csv

I have excel files which I want to convert to csv files. In those files I may have values like "1,234" which is one cell and I convert the commas to dot before I save the file as csv. So, this is my code:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = null;

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(source);
wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

wb.Worksheets[1].Cells.Replace(What: ",", Replacement: ".", LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart, SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: false, ReplaceFormat: false);
wb.SaveAs(target, XlFileFormat.xlCSVMSDOS, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Local: true);
wb.Close();
excel.Quit();
```

It works well enough. However, I just got a new file which has a comma as thousands separator. So the comma is visible in the cell, however when I double click it the comma is not there in both the csv and the excel file. Afterwards in code I parse the file by splitting the lines by ",". And the cell "1,234" which has comma as a thousands separator, is divided as 2 cells. How do I handle this?

Comment: It's a cell format issue - make sure it's formatted as "General" before exporting.

Comment: 1) why convert the file? xlsx files can be read by anyone 2) Why use Excel for this? You can use OLEDB or a library like EPPlus to read the xlsx file. Writing a CSV isn't that hard, but you can use CSVHelper to save some code

Comment: @CoolBots How would I do that with code?

Comment: 3) Your code itself is causing the conversion errors by replacing `,` with `.`. Excel *knows* which cells contain numbers. The thousand, decimal, list separators used in a CSV should be defined when exporting. When *imp* orting, the settings in the user's locale are used

Comment: @petko_stankoski why do you try to replace `,` with `.` in the first place? Is the cell a number or text?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That line is for both text and number fields. The problem is not in that line, the csv file gets converted as it should. The problem is afterwards in the parsing of the csv file, I need to ignore the thousands separator.

Comment: @petko_stankoski I believe there is a `Range` method that you can use to select cells; once selected, you can set `NumberFormat` property. Do this before saving the worksheet.

Comment: @petko_stankoski on the contrary, that *is* the problem. You are treating a numeric field as if it were a *text* field. A numeric field has no separators, it's a binary decimal value. If you specify the correct locale, or format, the CSV won't have any thousand separators. Second, by using Excel, you *lose* the ability to control the separators used when generating the final file. You are limited to either US or local system (which is what you used). That's just one of the reasons people don't use interop for conversions. The need to install Excel is the other